# Robolectric 2.1.1 testing that AsyncTask is started when pressing a button and test it's Results

Tags: android, robolectric

I am have an activity that presents two fields (username & password) for user login.

The login button executes an activity in the background (it checks against a remote server).

I am stuck at testing if the login activity is being executed and in capturing its results (if success it transitions to another activity, if fails displays a toast notification on the same activity).

Here is my code so far:

```
@Test
public void testLogIn_Valid() throws Exception { 
    mUsernameEditText.setText(VALID_USER); 
    mPasswordEditText.setText(VALID_PASSWORD); 

    mLoginButton.performClick(); 
}
```

How can I test or mock the success or failure of the asyncTask? And how can I test that the task was in fact started?

Comment: I'm working on something similar, I'm getting a stub exception right now. I'll be looking into a fix for a while.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for is testing the behaviour of your AsynTask, have a look at [this](https://github.com/playhaven/playhaven-robolectric/blob/master/src/test/java/com/xtremelabs/robolectric/shadows/AsyncTaskTest.java)

If on the contrary, you are trying to test the delegation of your action shout when you find the answer ^_^